# How to get master view controller in detail view controller with UISplitViewController?

Tags: ios, uisplitview

I have a `UISplitViewController` with master controller and detail controller:

```
MyMasterController *masterViewController = [[[MyMasterController alloc] initWithDirectory:directoryElement] autorelease];
MyDetailController *detailViewController = [[MyDetailController alloc] init];

masterViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;

UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.viewControllers = @[[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController], [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController]];
splitViewController.delegate = self;
```

The `MyDetailController` is a table list view controller, I want to master view controller run one method when user clicks on cell, So how to get the master controller in detail controller ?

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [master some_method]; // how to get ?
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use notifications instead, so in your master:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someMethod) name:@"DoSomeMethod" object:nil];

}

-(void) someMethod {

    ...

}
```

And in your detail:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DoSomeMethod" object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While jjv360s answer helps a lot, some surely want to pass values to the called method.
Following tutorial has helped me:

http://www.devfright.com/nsnotificationcenter-tutorial/

To pass the value `value`, you need to expose `value` as a property in the class that sends the notification. The receiving method needs to cast the `(id)`to the class that exposes the `value`.